# transfer/deposit ether on contract fails

Tags: solidity, ether, smart-contract-wallets, transfer

I am trying to deposit Ether on a smart contract. Looking at the documentation
my approach first looked like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.0.8;

contract SendEther {

    function deposit(uint256 amount) public payable {
        require(msg.value == amount);
    }
}
```

However, that failed with the following error message:

> [vm]
>
> from: 0x5c6...21678
>
> to: SendEther.deposit(uint256) 0xe63...4ddf5
>
> value: 0 wei
>
> data: 0xb6b...03039
>
> logs: 0
>
> hash: 0x50c...acc83
>
> status    false Transaction mined but execution failed
>
> transaction
> hash  0x50cb8aab1042aef79e8bf285346213a1edfa106b2a7421ee159da82b693acc83
>
> from  0x5c6B0f7Bf3E7ce046039Bd8FABdfD3f9F5021678
>
> to    SendEther.deposit(uint256)
> 0xe63D12C600b87F5da3C32C7cB3C1b1A84944ddf5 gas    3000000 gas transaction
> cost  21614 gas  execution cost   21614 gas  input    0xb6b...03039 decoded
> input {   "uint256 amount": "12345" } decoded output  {} logs [] val  0
> wei
>
> transact to SendEther.deposit errored: VM error: revert.
>
> revert    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
>
> Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the
> value you send should be less than your current balance.
>
> Debug the transaction to get more information.

Then I tried to use the transfer or call method to send Ether.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract SendEther {

    receive() external payable {}

    function sendViaTransfer(address payable to, uint256 amount) public payable {
        to.transfer(amount);
    }
}
```

Which resulted in this error:

> [vm]
>
> from: 0x147...C160C
>
> to: SendEther.sendViaTransfer(address,uint256) 0x70c...a304B
>
> value: 0 wei
>
> data: 0xd27...004d2
>
> logs: 0
>
> hash: 0xc29...0cf23
>
> status    false Transaction mined but execution failed
>
> transaction
> hash  0xc296ba642bca2e19c304a9e28381b3b523fdb86a94fcbc19e14ad5847a20cf23
>
> from  0x14723A09ACff6D2A60DcdF7aA4AFf308FDDC160C
>
> to    SendEther.sendViaTransfer(address,uint256)
> 0x70c001c84C723e3EfbF852D3e6AdaEb69A8a304B
>
> gas   3000000 gas
>
> transaction cost  29070 gas
>
> execution cost    29070 gas
>
> input 0xd27...004d2
>
> decoded input {
>
> "address to": "0x70c001c84C723e3EfbF852D3e6AdaEb69A8a304B",
>
> "uint256 amount": "1234"
>
> }
>
> decoded output    {}
>
> logs  []
>
> val   0 wei
>
> transact to SendEther.sendViaTransfer errored: VM error: revert.
>
> revert    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.

Trying to use "call" or "send" results in the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the first one looks like it should work (i.e. accept Eth on that contract) but according to the error output, you didn't send any Eth when you called it i.e. `value: 0 wei`. Are you using remix?

Comment: Yes, I am using remix.

Comment: make sure you set an amount to send in remix before you execute a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the log says message value is 0. Make sure to set VALUE in remix before clicking on the functions so it sends value

[image: set value to send when calling function]

Comment: yeah, that was my mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, for the first example, I don't think you need to `require(msg.value == amount)`. `msg.value` is the eth value sent to this contract. The `amount` parameter is not doing much there. And this function will revert if the `msg.value` sent is not the same as the `amount`. But anyways, doing this is redundant. But make sure that if you send an `amount` parameter of `5`, then you should send `5` weis as well so this function does not fail.

```js
function deposit(uint256 amount) public payable {
        require(msg.value == amount);
    }
```

The second example look fine. But your contract needs to have at least `amount` of balance or you should send a balance (`msg.value`) the same as the `amount` parameter.

```js
function sendViaTransfer(address payable to, uint256 amount) public payable {
        to.transfer(amount);
    }
```

I wrote some code with all the ways you can receive and send ether, with some comments, It might be helpful for you. All of the example work. Just remember to ether have enough balance in your `SendEther` contract before trying to send ether to another address, or send enough ether to that contract so it can use the `msg.value` and send that amount.

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Receiver {
    receive() external payable {}

    fallback() external payable {}

    function receiveBalance() public payable {}

    function getBalance() public view returns(uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    //.. Other functionalities here (withdraw, etc).
}

contract SendEther {

    address public owner = msg.sender;

    // Maybe you want to control who can withdraw the balance from this contract.
    modifier onlyOnwer() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function deposit(uint256 amount) public payable {
        require(msg.value == amount); // No need to send or check an amount here.
    }

    function deposit_v2() public payable {
        // We have the option to do nothing here. As long as the function is `payable`, we receive the eth.
    }

    // If you want to only receive eth without doing any special logic, then you can use `receive` and/or `fallback`.
    receive() external payable {}

    fallback() external payable {}

    // This function is `payable`, so this contract is receving some amount and sending `amount` to another address
    function sendViaTransfer(address payable to, uint256 amount) public payable onlyOnwer {

        // Maybe you want to check that this contract has enough balance to send the requested amount.
        require(address(this).balance >= amount, "Not enough balance in the contract.");

        to.transfer(amount);
    }

    // This function is `payable`, so this contract is receving some amount and sending that same amount (msg.value) to another address
    function sendViaTransfer_v2(address payable to) public payable onlyOnwer {
        to.transfer(msg.value);
    }

    // This function is `payable`, so this contract is receving some amount and sending `amount` to another address
    function sendViaSend(address payable to, uint256 amount) public payable onlyOnwer {

        // Maybe you want to check that this contract has enough balance to send the requested amount.
        require(address(this).balance >= amount, "Not enough balance in the contract.");

        bool success = to.send(amount);
        require(success, "Error sending eth");

    }

    // This function is `payable`, so this contract is receving some amount and sending that same amount (msg.value) to another address
    function sendViaSend_v2(address payable to) public payable onlyOnwer {
        bool success = to.send(msg.value);
        require(success, "Error sending eth");
    }

    // This function is `payable`, so this contract is receving some amount and sending `amount` to another address
    function sendViaCall(address payable to, uint256 amount) public payable onlyOnwer {

        // Maybe you want to check that this contract has enough balance to send the requested amount.
        require(address(this).balance >= amount, "Not enough balance in the contract.");

        (bool success, ) = to.call{value: amount}("");
        require(success, "Error sending eth");

    }

    // This function is `payable`, so this contract is receving some amount and sending that same amount (msg.value) to another address
    function sendViaCall_v2(address payable to) public payable onlyOnwer {
        (bool success, ) = to.call{value: msg.value}("");
        require(success, "Error sending eth");
    }

    // This function is `payable`, so this contract is receving some amount and sending `amount` to another address
    function sendViaCustomFunction(address payable to, uint256 amount) public payable onlyOnwer {

        // Maybe you want to check that this contract has enough balance to send the requested amount.
        require(address(this).balance >= amount, "Not enough balance in the contract.");

        Receiver(to).receiveBalance{value: amount}();

    }

    // This function is `payable`, so this contract is receving some amount and sending that same amount (msg.value) to another address
    function sendViaCustomFunction_v2(address payable to) public payable onlyOnwer {
        Receiver(to).receiveBalance{value: msg.value}();
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns(uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried your examples, but they throw the same error. Except for the deposit function, but I am still depositing 0 wei.